# Where does Bhagwan Parshuram live at present?

Tags: mahabharata, puranas, itihasa, parashurama

Bhagwan Parshuram is supposed to be immortal, but where does he live at present?

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Parashurama is currently living and meditating in the Mahendragiri mountains.

As for where and what the Mahendragiri mountains are:

These mountains are alluded to in both the Mahabaratha and in the Ramayana. It is mentioned in several Puranic texts, and it is one of the seven kula parvas:

> *Mahendro malayah sahyah suktiman*
> *rikshaparvatah*
> *Vindhyascha pariyatrascha saptatite*
> *kulaparvatah.* ([Vishnu Purana 2.3.3](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp060.htm))

The mountain range is found near the [Ganjam District](https://google.com/maps/place/Ganjam,+Odisha,+India) of Odisha.

Twice, Parashurama prayed on the hill, according to the [Bhagavata, 10.79.12](https://harekrsna.com/sun/features/02-10/features1642.htm), before he decided to make the hill his permanent place of being (Mahabaratha, Adi Parva, 129).

(More useful information about the Mahendragiri hills can be found [here](https://www.hindu-blog.com/2020/07/mahendragiri-in-hinduism.html).)